# How to disable a certain task scheduler history?

Tags: scheduled-tasks, history

Is there a way/method to disable a single task history logging? I running a script that will automate execution every minute, hence the history expand rapidly and cause lagging. **I want disable a single task history only, not All Tasks history**. If no, is there any way to handle this kind of situation of rapid logging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way/method to disable a single task history logging?

You cannot enable or disable event logging on a single task.  This is due to the fact, all the event logging, is going into a single event log.

> Unfortunately, you cannot enable history for specific tasks on Task
>   scheduler, this feature is default by design on Windows.

- [John Rubdy - Microsoft Community Forum Moderator](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-desktop/how-can-i-enable-or-disable-history-for-specific/7a9e5139-74cd-41a0-8822-083ce2017264)

> If no, is there any way to handle this kind of situation of rapid
>   logging?

You would have to use something other then a task.